# Adding routes to asterisk through the REST ARI

Tags: rest, asterisk, freepbx

I have an asterisk/freepbx server set up and working well.

I now need my external application to be able to add routes to the asterisk server, (it takes in a load of new phone numbers and is responsible for adding them to the asterisk server).  Is this possible to do through the REST API?

The calls need to be set up to an IVR, an mp3 playback or a conference...which is decided by the external application (the user isn't able to login to freepbx)

Answer (score 2):

No. You currently cannot manipulate the dialplan through ARI.

While there is an asterisk resource that provides some limited information about the running Asterisk process, the primary purpose of ARI is to let your write your own dialplan applications by handing control of the resources in Asterisk over to a third party application. It is not meant to replace AMI or AGI.

More information on the REST API in Asterisk can be found on the Asterisk wiki here: [Asterisk REST Interface (ARI)](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29395573).